# Creating a MongoDB index to enforce uniqueness for a field but only in combination with another value

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I am keeping track of some jobs in a collection. Each job has a name and a state. I want to enforce that there can only be one job with state "ACTIVE" for any given name. There can be many jobs for that same name in other states, but only one in ACTIVE.

I am using Java and Spring Data.

I tried this:

```
        IndexFilter onlyActive = PartialIndexFilter.of(Criteria.where("state").is("ACTIVE"));
        mongoTemplate.indexOps(DownloadJob.class)
        .ensureIndex(
            new Index().on("name", Sort.Direction.ASC).partial(onlyActive).unique()
        );
```

When I insert documents with the same name and different non-ACTIVE states I still get a duplicate key exception. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
        IndexFilter onlyActive = PartialIndexFilter.of(Criteria.where("state").is("ACTIVE"));
        mongoTemplate.indexOps(DownloadJob.class)
        .ensureIndex(
            new Index().on("name", Sort.Direction.ASC).unique().partial(onlyActive)
        );
```